# Should the moderator statistics include links to nomination posts under activity?

Tags: bug, election

On the [Moderator Statistics/Main Elections](http://elections.stackexchange.com/) page the recent activity includes links to the candidates' nomination posts.

[image: kiamlaluno's recent activity]

If only the last 5 entries for recent activity are going to be shown, should 2 of the spots be taken up by links guaranteed to be broken?

Comment: Those aren't deleted questions. Those are the "posts" that represent the nomination postings. They show up there for some reason, but they don't have titles and they're not ordinary posts, so they appear brokenly.

Comment: @animuson, thanks, I didn't know that. I guess my question still stands though. I'll reword it appropriately. (or I'll let Shog do it) :)

Comment: Yeah, this isn't ideal. I don't remember why it's this way (might be related to knowing that they are in fact the nomination posts), but I'll see what I can do about fixing it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah, that didn't make too much sense. This was cleared up in our transition to version 2.0 of the API, since this version doesn't return election-specific content like the old version did.

There will now also always be five activity entries under each contestant, since there were situations where that wasn't guaranteed to be the case. Changes will likely go out sometime toward the end of this week.